# Рекурсия JavaScript

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, функции

Не могу понять почему получаеться 8?
Как программа работает? Что за чем выполняеться?
В ступор вводит 3 строчка return 1;
Почему не вернется просто число 1?)

```
function power(base, exponent) {
   if (exponent == 0)
     return 1;
   else
     return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Любое число в нулевой степени, за исключением нуля, равно единице**. Потому, если exponent == 0 (это в Вашем случаи степень), то функция возвращает 1, ну а в ином случаи возводит число base в степень exponent.

P.S. А говорят математика программистам не нужна:)

P.P.S. Про рекурсию хорошо рассказано тут https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion

Comment: Спасибо =)
Теперь ясно)

Comment: Рад был помочь)